# How to send an image from frontend to back end?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

How to send an image from frontend(using ANGULARJS) to backend(Java) using g Ajax call.

That image I need to store in local server. Using streams.?

Comment: Read up on ajax. Angular docs right here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.

Comment: Thanks dastur. But here I am not passing URL...from UI I am capturing one div element as an image format... that image I need to send.

Comment: If you are able to capture one div as an image format then you can just post that image to server with http.post request

Comment: @MADHUSUDHANRAJUKURAPATI Have you ever consider using ftp client to send an file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a file input (which can be hidden and activated by clicking another element).

Once you have a file input with a file in it, you can append the file to a FormData object and submit it as the post body in an ajax request.

```
var data = new FormData()
var file = document.getElementById('my-file-element').files[0]
data.set('key', file)

// Send ajax as normal with formdata body.
```

[FormData Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)

---

Edit: based on your comments

Looks like you want to take a "screenshot" of a div.

For that your best bet is to [add the dom to a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) and then convert the canvas to a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob). Then submit the blob as per my example above.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some angular made modules for uploading, i have only used these 2, they could work for your project maybe, they work just the same as making an ajax call but simplier and with several custom options

1. https://github.com/leon/angular-upload
2. https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload