# "Required part 'image' is not present" error message when sending FormData from frontend to SpringBoot backend

Tags: spring-boot, next.js, axios, multipartform-data, multipartfile

I'm sending an image file from frontend inside a FormData object. I set 'multipart/form-data' as the Content-Type of the request in the headers section of axios and set the controller in my backend to consume multipart/form-data.

But when I do the POST request, the backend returns this error: "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required part 'image' is not present"
But if I do the request through Postman and not through my frontend, the backend recognises the MultiPartFile file.

This is the axios POST request in my frontend:

```
const image = new FormData();
        image.append("image", payload)
        response = await axiosClient.post(URL, image, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            validateStatus: function (status) {
                return true;
            }
        })
```

And this is the HTML form where I'm getting the image:

```
      <form>
        <div>
          <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*"/>
        </div>
      </form>
```

This is the body of the request as seen in the Network tab of the browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W201Y.png)

And the headers of the request in the Network tab: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1kxB.png)

This is my backend controller (I'm using SpringBoot):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{id}/image", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public ResponseEntity<VideoGameDTO> addImage(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image, @PathVariable UUID id) throws IOException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(mapper
            .toDto(addImageUseCase.addImage(image, id)), HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
```

And this is the request done in Postman that works: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TATDg.png)

I don't know where the problem is because I know thanks to Postman that the backend is working properly and I can see with the Network tab of the browser that the file is sent as it should.

Comment: I solved it. The problem was in the way I was sending the image file to the axios service. I was sending the "value" of image div instead of the .files[0]. It is better seen in the first answer of this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603031/how-to-send-an-image-from-frontend-to-back-end